# Why am I unable to view stats in the WSO2 API Manager Store?

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

Everyone please note that this question has been updated as I've recently had logs to work with.  Below the log is the original posting with my configs, and the behavior I was seeing.
Today, WSO2 APIM continues to send to BAM receivers which update the Stats database.  However when I click on any of the statistics link in the publisher I get:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-03-04 13:43:18,815] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} -  Error while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: Error occurred while querying from JDBC database
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryFirstAccess(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:1747)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.getFirstAccessTime(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:1675)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getFirstAccessTime(APIProviderHostObject.java:2911)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c1._c_getFirstAccessTime_13(/publisher/modules/statistics/usage.jag:351)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c1.call(/publisher/modules/statistics/usage.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/statistics/module.jag:29)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c0.call(/publisher/modules/statistics/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag:220)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag:4)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1427)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryFirstAccess(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:1729)
        ... 63 more
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-03-04 13:43:18,836] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag}
```

I have configured WSo2 API Manager 1.6.0 and BAM 2.4.0 to both use the same datasource configuration for WSO2AM_STATS_DB.
For the store it is a single WSO2AM_STATS_DB entry that matches the entry on the BAM server (below) and API-Manager.xml is updated to:

```
  <APIUsageTracking>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
<PublisherClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher</PublisherClass>
        <ThriftPort>7612</ThriftPort>
        <BAMServerURL>tcp://myBAMserver:7612/</BAMServerURL>
        <BAMUsername>user</BAMUsername>
        <BAMPassword>pwd</BAMPassword>
        <DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName>
        <GoogleAnalyticsTracking>
             <Enabled>false</Enabled>
             <TrackingID>UA-XXXXXXXX-X</TrackingID>
       </GoogleAnalyticsTracking>
    </APIUsageTracking>
```

and now the datasource for APIM:

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
            <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mydbserver:1433/wso2_apiStatsdb</url>
            <username>wso2storeuser</username>
            <password>storepwd</password>
            <driverClassName>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
 </datasource>
```

For the BAM server here are my datasources:

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mydbserver:1433/wso2_carbondb</url>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>pwd</password>
                <driverClassName>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mydbserver:1433/wso2_apiStatsdb</url>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>pwd</password>
                <driverClassName>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
     </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2BAM_DATASOURCE</name>
        <description>The datasource used for analyzer data</description>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mydbserver:1433/wso2_apiStatsdb</url>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>pwd</password>
                <driverClassName>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

        <datasource>
        <name>WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DATASOURCE</name>
        <description>The datasource used for Cassandra data</description>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9161/EVENT_KS</url>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2BAM_UTIL_DATASOURCE</name>
        <description>The datasource used for BAM utilities, such as message store etc..</description>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9161/BAM_UTIL_KS</url>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <!-- The URL configs are loaded from cassandra-component.xml -->
    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2BAM_HIVE_INCREMENTAL_DATASOURCE</name>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
                <dataSourceProps>
                    <property name="replicationFactor">1</property>
                    <property name="strategyClass">org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy</property>
                    <property name="readConsistencyLevel">QUORUM</property>
                    <property name="writeConsistencyLevel">QUORUM</property>
                    <property name="keyspaceName">HIVE_INCREMENTAL_KS</property>
                </dataSourceProps>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

When I look in mydbserver/wso2_apiStatsdb I see that the following tables were created and have been updated with data:

API_REQUEST_SUMMARY, API_Resource_USAGE_SUMMARY
update:  some additional tables have been added and updated...
API_FAULT_SUMMARY, API_RESPONSE_SUMMARY, API_VERSION_USAGE_SUMMARY

However when I go to the publisher page I get:
[image]

As far as I can tell I've updated the publisher/store and gateway/key manager to send data to the BAM server.  The BAM server appears to process and put that summarized data in the sql server database.  My entries for SQL server database match for the publisher/store config and the BAM server config.  Does anyone have any ideas what I'm missing that will enable me to see the stats when in the publisher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gammonster, this has been figured out. It appears that the devil is indeed in the details - the runtime was trying to execute a sql query using the 'limit' keyword in a SQL Server database and SQL Server does not support 'limit'. It has 'top' instead.

Would have appreciated if the product documentation expressly identified SQL Server to not be a preferred DB instance for BAM.

Comment: Or perhaps if SQL Server had been included in the codeset and had SQL that uses 'top'.

Comment: Same issue here. What is your solution to this issue? Did you change wso2 code and recompile it?

Answer (score 1):

Can u please check if the `EnableBillingAndUsage` is set to `false`. This is available in conf/api-manager.xml

```
<EnableBillingAndUsage>false</EnableBillingAndUsage>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  The setting is currently set to false on the Store/Publisher server.  Since the database is being written to I must be missing some easy piece of config...

Comment: How about the gateway is the config set to false in that too?

Comment: It is also false, here is the config section: <EnableBillingAndUsage>false</EnableBillingAndUsage> <APIUsageTracking><Enabled>true</Enabled><PublisherClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher</PublisherClass><ThriftPort>7612</ThriftPort><BAMServerURL>tcp://myBAMServer:7612</BAMServerURL> <BAMUsername>admin</BAMUsername><BAMPassword>admin</BAMPassword><DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName> <GoogleAnalyticsTracking><Enabled>false</Enabled>         <TrackingID>UA-XXXXXXXX-X</TrackingID></GoogleAnalyticsTracking></APIUsageTracking>

Comment: I've started getting the following in my store/pub logs:  ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} -  Error while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: Error occurred while querying from JDBC database

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.  TID: [0] [AM] [2014-02-17 12:03:31,453] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag}

Comment: Those errors happen whenever I click on All Stats or Stats in the publisher.  I've trimmed some details so I can add the full error if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the BAM on port offset 1? As far as I can see you have BAM running on a different server. Try running BAM with port offset 1. The default config provided in the site is for a usecase where API Manager and BAM runs on the same server with port offsets (API M -0 and BAM -1). Hence all the relevant thrift ports are also incremented by 1 in the default config. Hence I suggest you to run BAM on offset 1.

In the meantime pls check if the MQSQL DB that has summarized stats contain any data inside them.

Comment: I had already confirmed that the tables API_REQUEST_SUMMARY, API_Resource_USAGE_SUMMARY are being written to.  Should there be additional?

Comment: I've verified that when BAM starts up the log notes: Thrift port: 7612 {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener}

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you haven't configured the summarized database correctly in API Manager. From what you have mentioned, API Manager seems to publish data correctly, but it's not fetching summarized data. Please see if you have defined WSO2AM_STATS_DB in master-datasources.xml inside APIM directory.

Comment: The definition for API Manager WSO2AM_STATS_DB matches the definition of the BAM servers master-datasources.xml (with the exception that the user/pwd is different).  So BAM should be writing to those tables, an d APIM reading from those same tables.

Comment: Do you see any errors in API Manager Console when loading the Statistics Page? And do you get the same view when trying to load All Statistics page?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the wso2carbon.log file and no errors are presented to the publisher console.  I just get the stock display that I have attached in the original question.  I get the same stock display when attempting to access All Statistics or Statistics

Comment: One thing you can do is trying to Query the tables (API_REQUEST_SUMMARY, API_Resource_USAGE_SUMMARY), by connecting to the Database with the credentials you have provided for API Manager. If you don't see any data, then there could be a problem with the data analyzing part.

Comment: I've updated the original question to include my master-datasources.xml entry from APIM.  Just in case I have a typo or something...

Comment: A good idea, that is how I have been checking the database so far.  I have additional tables present with data, so now the tables I see are: API_REQUEST_SUMMARY, API_Resource_USAGE_SUMMARY
API_FAULT_SUMMARY, API_RESPONSE_SUMMARY, API_VERSION_USAGE_SUMMARY.  I don't know if I'm missing some and that is why APIM is confused?

Comment: Are you using a distributed deployment? The config files you have provided- are those of the publisher node?

Comment: I have a APIM server that is running a Publisher and Store, a gateway server that is running the gateway and key manager, and a BAM server.  the config files above are from the Publisher and Store as well as the BAM server (I have noted above the config snip which area it applies to).

Comment: Do you have any summarized data inside any of the tables - say  API_REQUEST_SUMMARY

Comment: API_REQUEST_SUMMARY has 5 rows,  API_Resource_USAGE_SUMMARY has 15 rows, API_RESPONSE_SUMMARY has 15 rows, API_VERSION_USAGE_SUMMARY has 15 rows.